# Use rvest package to scrape aviation safety data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to R and have 0 experience in web programming.
Now I was assigned a project to wrangle and visualize aviation safety data.
I searched data online and got the website here http://aviation-safety.net/database/
I am interested in the aircraft type, year, country and airline subcategories, how can I use rvest to grab those data down as data frames?

This is like a free ride question, but scraping is just beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `rvest` makes this really simple. Take e.g. the link to the 1919 data, then

```
library(rvest)

read_html("http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919") %>%
  html_table()

[[1]]
         date            type registration operator fat.            location    pic cat
1 02-AUG-1919   Caproni Ca.48               Caproni   14              Verona NA  NA  A1
2 11-AUG-1919 Felixstowe Fury         N123      RAF    1 near Felixtowe RNAS NA  NA  A1
```

And the links should be straight-forward to do even without scraping them, right? To get the countries from the pictures, you'd have to select the flag image titles

```
read_html("http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=1919") %>%
  html_nodes(".innertube > table") %>%
  html_nodes(".list > img") %>% html_attr("title") %>% na.omit()

[1] "Italy" "U.K." 
attr(,"na.action")
```

Comment: But what if I want to get all the data instead of by single year or country, I mean year could be easier as i can do a loop on that, what about the country?

Comment: Then you have to combine it with `rbind`, since it comes from various URLs. Just put them all in an lapply loop or so -